# Azure Dev Ops .NET API Add Test Results Error : TestPointId, testCaseId, testCaseRevision, testCaseTitle must be specified for planned test results

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, .net-standard

I am getting the error "One or more errors occurred. (TestPointId, testCaseId, testCaseRevision, testCaseTitle must be specified for planned test results.)", when trying to add a test result to a programmatically created manual test run in Azure Dev Ops. I wasn't getting this error when AzureDevOps was hosted on on-prem servers but since the deployment to Azure Cloud, I have been facing this issue. Some more information about my environment

OS: Windows 10

VS Version: VS 2022 (64 Bit) - 17.8.3

Framework : .NET Standard 2.0

Language : C# v10.0

NuGet:

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client - 19.231.0-preview

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client - 19.231.0-preview

Below is my code

**Models:**

```
public class TestResultOutcomeUpdateModel
{
    public int TestPlanId { get; set; }

    public int TestSuiteId { get; set; }

    public int TestCaseId { get; set; }

    public int PointId { get; set; }

    public int TestRunId { get; set; }

    public Outcome Outcome { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public RunState TestState { get; set; }

    public double DurationInMs { get => (EndTime - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds; }

    public bool? ResetToActive { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

**Main Code:**

```
public class TestMain
{
    #region Public Methods

    public void Test()
    {
        const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "azuredevopspat";

        const string URL_KEY = "azuredevopsurl";

        string Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[URL_KEY];
        string Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ACCESS_TOKEN];
        VssConnection _VssConnection ??= new VssConnection(new Uri(Url), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, Token));

        TestManagementHttpClient _TestManagementHttpClient = _VssConnection?.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

        IdentityRef _IdentityRef = new IdentityRef() { DisplayName = _VssConnection.AuthorizedIdentity.DisplayName };

        const string _ProjectName = "TEST1";
        int planId = 1;
        int suiteId = 2;
        int testCaseId = 3;
        TestRunState runState = TestRunState.NeedsInvestigation;
        string testRunName = "Build#1.11_Test";

        // initializers with default values
        int testRunId = default!;
        bool updated = false;
        try
        {
            // Create a Test Run
            RunCreateModel rcm = new(testRunName, string.Empty, null, new ShallowReference() { Id = planId.ToString() }, null, 0, string.Empty, null, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, DateTime.Now.ToString("O"), string.Empty, null, null, null, null, _IdentityRef);

            testRunId = _TestManagementHttpClient.CreateTestRunAsync(rcm, _ProjectName).Result.Id;

            // Add Test Result to test run
            IList<TestResultOutcomeUpdateModel> testResultOutcomeUpdateModels = new List<TestResultOutcomeUpdateModel>() { new TestResultOutcomeUpdateModel()
        {
            TestPlanId= planId,
            TestSuiteId= suiteId,
            TestCaseId = testCaseId,
            TestRunId = testRunId,
            ResetToActive = null,
            Outcome = Outcome.Failed,
            ErrorMessage = "Exception",
            StartTime= DateTime.Now,
            EndTime= DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TestState = RunState.Completed
        } });

            IList<TestCaseResult> testCaseResults = new List<TestCaseResult>();

            // Iterate each ResultOutcomeUpdateModel
            testResultOutcomeUpdateModels.ForEach(trocum =>
            {
                // Get Point Id
                // Get test points associated with a testplan id, suite id, and test case id
                List<TestPoint> points = _TestManagementHttpClient.GetPointsAsync(_ProjectName, trocum.TestPlanId, trocum.TestSuiteId, null, null, trocum.TestCaseId.ToString()).Result;

                TestPoint? pnt = points?.First();

                // populate the model value
                trocum.PointId = pnt?.Id ?? 0;

                // Attach the test result to test run
                ShallowReference testPoint = new()
                {
                    Id = pnt?.Id.ToString(),
                    Url = pnt?.Url
                };

                // with the latest hosting to cloud, the testpoint is returning null for test plan and suite, so basically making sure that we have null check
                TestCaseResult trcm = new()
                {
                    TestPlan = pnt?.TestPlan ?? new ShallowReference() { Id = trocum.TestPlanId.ToString() },
                    TestSuite = pnt?.Suite ?? new ShallowReference() { Id = trocum.TestSuiteId.ToString() },
                    TestRun = new ShallowReference(trocum.TestRunId.ToString()),
                    TestPoint = testPoint,
                    TestCase = new ShallowReference(pnt?.TestCase) { Id = pnt?.TestCase.Id, Name = pnt?.TestCase?.Name, Url = pnt?.TestCase.Url },
                    StartedDate = trocum.StartTime,
                    TestCaseReferenceId = int.Parse(pnt?.TestCase?.Id ?? "0"),
                    TestCaseRevision = pnt?.Revision ?? 1,
                    TestCaseTitle = pnt?.TestCase?.Name,
                    RunBy = _IdentityRef
                };

                // Add TestResults to Test Runs
                // Note : this won't update the outcome of the testpoint and won't get reflected in TestCase View

                // ERROR: throwing the following error Here -> "One or more errors occurred. (TestPointId, testCaseId, testCaseRevision, testCaseTitle must be specified for planned test results.)"
                TestCaseResult[] addedTrcm = _TestManagementHttpClient.AddTestResultsToTestRunAsync(new TestCaseResult[1] { trcm }, _ProjectName, trocum.TestRunId).Result.ToArray();

                // Update test result once created to get reflected in Test cases
                addedTrcm[0].Outcome = trocum.Outcome.ToString();
                addedTrcm[0].CompletedDate = trocum.EndTime;
                addedTrcm[0].DurationInMs = trocum.DurationInMs;
                addedTrcm[0].State = trocum.TestState.ToString();
                addedTrcm[0].ErrorMessage = trocum.ErrorMessage;

                // Update test results and add it to the list for update status comparison
                testCaseResults.AddRange(_TestManagementHttpClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(addedTrcm, _ProjectName, trocum.TestRunId).Result);
            });

            _ = testCaseResults.Count == testResultOutcomeUpdateModels.Count;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Update the test run state
            RunUpdateModel rum = new(testRunName, (DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).ToString("o"), string.Empty, runState.ToString());

            _ = _TestManagementHttpClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(rum, _ProjectName, testRunId).Result;
        }
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

I don't understand why its complaining about "a planned test results".

I have also seeing others facing similar issue in the past - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/318.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

I have also tried upgrading and downgrading NuGet packages but that didn't help either.